# Pasar variables php a funcion onClick

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script>
$.fn.Recibe = function(id,p) {
        alert(id+' '+p);
} 
</script>

En PHP
$diPesca=1;
$var="Enviar parametrosa funcion js";

$fila="<div title='click para enviar' ";
$fila .=" onClick=\"$(this).Recibe('".$idPesca."','".$var."');\">";
$fila .="aqui";

$fila ."</div>";
echo $fila
```

Comment: Amigo, mejor sería si mostrases más código, mejor formateado, y explicases cual es el problema que tienes, qué has intentado y que deseas conseguir. Si no, dificilmente te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Julio, bienvenido a SOes. Trata de explicar un poco mas que es lo que necesitas para que podamos ayudarte. Revisa [ask] para una mejor comprension de este punto.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero implementarlo así:

```js
<script>
function Recibe(id, p) {
 alert(id+' '+p);
}
</script>
```

En PHP

```
$idPesca=1; 
$var="Enviar parametrosa funcion js";
$fila="<div title='click para enviar' "; 
$fila .="onClick=\"Recibe('".$idPesca."','".$var."');\">"; 
$fila .="aqui";
$fila ."</div>";
```

Espero te sirva! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

NO queda claro si tienes dudas o estas consultando, pero segun entiendo, ajusta algunas lineas a tu código:

```
<script>
    $.fn.Recibe = function(id,p) {
    alert(id+' '+p);
    } 
</script>

<?php
$idPesca=1;
$var="Enviar parametrosa funcion js";

$fila="<div title='click para enviar' ";
$fila .=" onclick='$(this).Recibe($idPesca,\"$var\");'>";
$fila .="aqui";

$fila .="</div>";
echo $fila;
?>
```

Supongo ya estas importando la librería de JQuery.
Sin Jquery seria:

```
<script>
    Recibe = function(id,p) {
    alert(id+' '+p);
    } 
</script>

<?php
$idPesca=1;
$var="Enviar parametrosa funcion js";

$fila="<div title='click para enviar' ";
$fila .=" onclick='Recibe($idPesca,\"$var\");'>";
$fila .="aqui";

$fila .="</div>";
echo $fila;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, tienes algunos errores de sintaxis;

1. la variable **$idPesca** no esta declarada tu, tu lo tienes como **diPesca**.
2. Toda linea de PHP se termina en **;** tu linea del echo no termina en ;.
3. En la penultima linea no estas concatenando la variable fila te falta el **=**.
   Te anexo las correcciones:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   Y Considero que a eso se debe el echo que no puedas pasar los parámetros de PHP a JS, lo probé con las correcciones que te muestro y funciona.

Nota: no olvides importar la biblioteca de JQuery para que funcione.

Comment: En lugar de imágenes, es más útil para todos que coloques el texto del código con todo el bloque formateado como código.